# jquery load -> doesn't load specific php file but webpage 2 times (yii2)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii2

I have a little problem with using jquery load. I'm using the yii framework (yii2) and wanted to make a simple:

- don't load all the items from the start
- only if pressed load more: load three more items

It all looked similar to this:

**main.php**

standard yii2 layout main.php

**content.php**

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\StringHelper;

$this->title = 'Website';
?>
<div id="postItems">
    <?php
        $px=0;
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $i => $model) { ?>    
        <?php if($px==5) {break;} ?>
        <?php $px++ ?>
        <div id='<?php echo Html::encode($model->id) ?>' class="col-lg-4 cc2" >
            <h2><?php echo Html::encode($model->title) ?></h2>
            <small class="text-muted ca">Created at: <?php echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_at) ?></small>
            <div >
            <?php echo StringHelper::truncateWords(Html::tag('p', Html::encode($model->body), [ 'class'=> 'fob']), 20) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="cbtn ">
    <a class="btn btn-success pi-load">Load more</a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam gravida, nisl sit amet commodo ullamcorper, enim risus blandit leo, eu dapibus eros nisl eu lacus. Sed at eros id magna bibendum euismod. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam sed diam a orci aliquam efficitur. Ut quis feugiat ligula. Curabitur non malesuada nisi. Pellentesque tempor mollis arcu et facilisis. Nullam a iaculis mi. Nulla pharetra vestibulum ultricies. Praesent eu sem pretium, malesuada ipsum eu, rhoncus ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus diam ut ex vulputate sagittis a in nibh. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris lobortis varius dolor a porttitor.<p>
</div>
```

**js file (linked over AppAsset)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pitemCount = 5;
    $(".pi-load").click(function(){
        pitemCount = pitemCount + 3;
        $("#postItems").load("load-postItems.php", {
            pitemNewCount: pitemCount
        });
    });
});
```

**load-postItems.php**

```
<?php
    $px=0;
    $pitemNewCount= $_POST['pitemNewCount'];
?>
<?php foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $i => $model) { ?>    
    <?php if($px==$pitemNewCount) {break;} ?>
    <?php $px++ ?>
    <div id='<?php echo Html::encode($model->id) ?>' class="col-lg-4 cc2" >
        <h2><?php echo Html::encode($model->title) ?></h2>
        <small class="text-muted ca">Created at: <?php echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_at) ?></small>
        <div >
        <?php echo StringHelper::truncateWords(Html::tag('p', Html::encode($model->body), [ 'class'=> 'fob']), 20) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now, the problem is that instead of loading the php (`load-postItems.php`) file with the higher item count, it's seeming to load the whole page (`main.php` and `content.php`), a second time, on top.

I don't know if i overlooked something, or if this is the yii(2) framework blocking the action. But overall I'm happy about all the help I can get.

**EDIT #1:**

I tried @Jay Blachard's way of specifying it and it worked to the point that it didn't load the whole page again, but in turn it didn't load the specified part too.

I'm going to look into the logs and try to make some sense through that.

Comment: That is how `load()` works, it loads everything requested unless you specify a tag to load.  For example `$("#postItems").load("load-postItems.php" "#div");` In order to do . an append you would have to do something different.

Comment: View the raw response in your browser's network inspector.  Does it contain "the whole page"?  If so, then yes, it seems to be a result of the request going through the framework instead of to an independent file.  I'm not very familiar with yii2, but I'm sure there's a way to disable the default template and only get the output generated by the target file/action.

Comment: nice jay i didnt know you could drill down like that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a URL that just spits out the relevant bit of HTML, disabling any templates etc. It sounds like you are calling the full page, which would include your html templates etc. Make another endpoint rather than parsing the full HTML to get the bit you want.

Even better would be if the enpoint returned a JSON object, and then you can build up the elements in JS.